# NoReverseMatch at /cars/

Tags: python, django

i am working on a project .
i use crispy_form in my project.

it is my cars urls.py::

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'cars'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.CarsListView.as_view(), name='cars'),
    path('add-car/', views.AddCarView.as_view(), name='add_car'),
    path('car/', views.RepairsListView.as_view(), name='car_detail'),
    path('car/<int:pk>/update/', views.UpdateCarView.as_view(), name='update_car'),
    path('car/<int:pk>/delete/', views.DeleteCarView.as_view(), name='delete_car'),
    path('car/<int:pk>/new-repair/', views.AddRepairView.as_view(), name='add_repair'),
]
```

it is my cars views.py ::

```
from .models import Car, Repair
from django.views.generic import ListView, UpdateView, DeleteView, CreateView
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.contrib import messages

class CarsListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Car
    template_name = 'cars/cars.html'
    context_object_name = 'cars'
    paginate_by = 10

    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.request.GET.get('q'):
            q = self.request.GET.get('q')
            make_results = self.model.objects.filter(
                user=self.request.user, make=q).order_by('-pk')
            model_results = self.model.objects.filter(
                user=self.request.user, model=q).order_by('-pk')
            if make_results.exists():
                return make_results
            elif model_results.exists():
                return model_results
            else:
                return self.model.objects.none()
        return self.model.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).order_by('-pk')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['q'] = self.request.GET.get('q', '')
        return context



class AddCarView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Car
    fields = ['make', 'model', 'vrn', 'year']
    success_url = '/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)




class DeleteCarView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Car
    success_url = '/'

    def test_func(self):
        if self.get_object().user == self.request.user:
            return True
        return False

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        success_message = f'Car {self.get_object()} has been deleted'
        messages.success(self.request, success_message)
        return super().delete(request, *args, **kwargs)




class UpdateCarView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Car
    fields = ['make', 'model', 'vrn', 'year']
    success_message = 'Car info has been updated'

    def get_success_url(self, **kwargs):
        row = self.request.GET.get('row')
        p = self.request.GET.get('p')
        q = self.request.GET.get('q')
        options = '?p=' + p + '&row=' + row
        options += '&q=' + q
        messages.success(self.request, self.success_message)
        return reverse_lazy('car_detail') + options

    def test_func(self):
        if self.get_object().user == self.request.user:
            return True
        return False




class AddRepairView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Repair
    fields = ['date', 'description']
    success_message = 'New repair has been added'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['car'] = Car.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form, **kwargs):
        form.instance.car = Car.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self, **kwargs):
        row = self.request.GET.get('row')
        p = self.request.GET.get('p')
        q = self.request.GET.get('q')
        options = '?p=' + p + '&row=' + row
        options += '&q=' + q
        return reverse_lazy('car_detail') + options




class RepairsListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Repair
    paginate_by = 10

    def __get_car(self):
        cars = Car.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).order_by('-pk')
        if self.request.GET.get('q'):
            q = self.request.GET.get('q')
            make_results = Car.objects.filter(
                user=self.request.user, make=q).order_by('-pk')
            model_results = Car.objects.filter(
                user=self.request.user, model=q).order_by('-pk')
            if make_results.exists():
                cars = make_results
            elif model_results.exists():
                cars = model_results

        id = int(self.request.GET.get('row')) - 1
        page = int(self.request.GET.get('p')) - 1
        id = id + page * 10
        return cars[id]

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['car'] = self.__get_car()
        context['row'] = self.request.GET.get('row')
        context['p'] = self.request.GET.get('p')
        context['q'] = self.request.GET.get('q')
        return context

    def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
        return self.model.objects.filter(car=self.__get_car()).order_by('-pk')
```

and it is my users views.py ::

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, PasswordChangeForm
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin


class RegisterUser(CreateView):
    form_class = UserCreationForm


    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, 'users/register-user.html', {'form': UserCreationForm()})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            login(request, user)
            messages.success(request, f'Welcome, {username}!')
            return redirect('cars')
        return render(request, 'users/register-user.html', {'form': form})



class ChangePassword(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    form_class = PasswordChangeForm

    template_name = 'users/change-password'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = PasswordChangeForm(request.user)
        return render(request, 'users/change-password.html', {'form': form})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = PasswordChangeForm(request.user, request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            update_session_auth_hash(request, user)
            messages.success(request, 'Password changed!')
            return redirect('cars')
        return render(request, 'users/change-password.html', {'form': form})
```

and when i want to cars page i have error :: ((NoReverseMatch at /cars/))
and
(Reverse for 'login' not found. 'login' is not a valid view function or pattern name.)

can anyone help me??
please help me guys!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to include your cars and user Url into your base urls.py.

```
from yourproject.cars import urls as car_urls
from yourproject.users import urls as users_urls
```

and then add the following to your base urlpatterns

```
url(r"^cars/", include((car_urls)),
url(r"^users/", include((user_urls)),
```

Comment: when i do this ihave an error in server ::: ((  'from yourproject.cars import urls as car_urls
from yourproject.users import urls as users_urls ' )))